# Expanding ListView and Clickable image

Tags: c#, wpf, image, listview, mvvm

I have two questions.

**Q1:** I have a `ListView` and I want `OnSelectedItem` to expand the attributes and show more attributes. Is this possible? How? [I have the attributes in the `ObservableCollection`]

**Q2:** I want to put a clickable image inside the view, that will change ViewModel (chat behavior). Is this possible? How?

**ListView**

```
<ListView x:Name="dataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Friends}" Height="314" BorderThickness="0" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemFriends}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="Resources\Images\ic_status.png" Height="24" Width="18"/>
                    <StackPanel Margin="5" Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding name}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding lastLocation}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding timestamp}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Don't put tags into question title, that's what the tags are for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A1:** In datatemplate, create how you would like the extended attributes to appear and place them in a container such as a stack panel.

Then use an DataTrigger using the IsSelected property to change the visibility of the stack panel container from visible and collapsed as needed.

**A2:** The easiest way would be to use a Button with the content source set to an image as this will give you the click event/command binding to play with.

EDIT: Example of the first answer could look like:

```
 <ListView x:Name="dataGrid" Height="314" BorderThickness="0" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItemFriends}" ItemsSource="{Binding Friends}" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <Image Source="Resources\Images\ic_status.jpg" Height="24" Width="18"/>
                    <StackPanel Margin="5" Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        <StackPanel x:Name="AdditionItems" Orientation="Vertical" Visibility="Collapsed">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastLocation}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TimeStamp}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="AdditionItems" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

I have run this code and it works for me, it should be enough to put you on the right track. The important things to note are that the trigger is attached to the ListViewItem, it will trigger when it the IsSelected property turns true, it will then change the visibility of the StackPanel called "Additional Items" to visible from collapsed.

[image: My Example Window]

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for your answer. A1: can you write a small example just for me to understand better? A2: Nice idea, I think I will implement in the way you are saying :D

Comment: Hi Antoine, was the answer acceptable? If so please rate it

Comment: Hi @Ben Steele sorry for the time taken but it worked. Genius solution can you help me just to unselect all the items when I change view model? I choose your answer as the correct one. Cheers

Comment: Firstly, thanks for ranking the answer. To answer your question:

You can call the Unselect.all() method on your listbox

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.unselectall(v=vs.110).aspx